# How to swipe fragments without using Viewpager or Viewpager2 in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

I want to swipe between the fragments without using any viewpager, Viewpager makes my application very slow performance after using 2-3 minutes. Please suggest me any alternate solution.
Thanks.

I tried by replacing the tablayout with recyclerview for tabs, but still having the same low performance issue. application getting very slow after swiping the fragements many times.

Comment: Try looking at [How to make a Bottom Navigation Activity change fragments by swipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60261907/how-to-make-a-bottom-navigation-activity-change-fragments-by-swipe)